# how to avoid repeating myself in consecutive error handling

Tags: go

I have the following handling of consecutive errors:

```
nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
if err != nil {                           // This error handling  
    pr := progressRes{                    // is Just a copy of
        Type:        progressResponse,    // error handling
        Message:     err.Error(),         // for the next error,
        MessageType: errorMessage,        // what is the
        Progress:    100,                 // best practice
    }                                     // to avoid
    go response(ws, pr.json())            // repeating myself here
    return                                // without making the code
}                                         // complicated
links, err := model.AllLinks()
if err != nil {
    pr := progressRes{
        Type:        progressResponse,
        Message:     err.Error(),
        MessageType: errorMessage,
        Progress:    100,
    }
    go response(ws, pr.json())
    return
}
```

What is the best practice to avoid repeating myself in the above code without making the code complex? I can think of adding a new `func`, however I just thought there might be a better idea which I'm not aware of.

Comment: If you're concerned about repetition, the only option I can think of that is less verbose than an error handling func is `panic`-ing, otherwise known as an exception.

Comment: @iPherian Thanks. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @iPherian Please don't suggest `panic`ing for a normal error handling situation. `panic`ing should only be used in situations where there is a fundamentally broken piece of logic in the code and the panic could have been avoided. A great example is the `reflect` package. In the case of errors in a web application (like it seems to be the case here), errors should be handled gracefully with the classic `if err != nil` over and over.

Comment: You could handle this error type in the calling function. Then it will only need handling once. For web applications I usually let the errors percolate up to the top level and have a few response encoders to deal with the various error and success scenarios. It helps to have defined an appropriate error type for the application - os.PathError is a good source of inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are repeating a number of steps in multiple places the correct approach would be to abstract away those steps into a procedure, which is what programming is about. This applies to error handling just as well as to any other parts of your program.

One option:

```
func allNodesAndLinks() ([]*Node, []*Link, error) {
    nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    links, err := model.AllLinks()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    return nodes, links, nil
}

// ...

nodes, links, err := allNodesAndLinks()
if err != nil {
    pr := progressRes{
        Type:        progressResponse,
        Message:     err.Error(),
        MessageType: errorMessage,
        Progress:    100,
    }
    go response(ws, pr.json())
    return
}
```

Another option:

```
func respondWithError(ws io.Writer, err error) {
    pr := progressRes{
        Type:        progressResponse,
        Message:     err.Error(),
        MessageType: errorMessage,
        Progress:    100,
    }
    response(ws, pr.json())
}

// ...

nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
if err != nil {
    go respondWithError(ws, err)
    return
}
links, err := model.AllLinks()
if err != nil {
    go respondWithError(ws, err)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two different approaches you can use; either `defer` or, as you suggested, using another function.

Defer would work like this:

```
// All of these must be defined before we call defer.
var err error
var progressResponse string
var errorMessage string
defer func() {
    // Since the deferred function will be called even if
    // the function has completed successfully, we need to
    // check that there actually has been an error before we
    // create the error response.
    if err == nil {
        return
    }
    pr := progressRes{
        Type:        progressResponse,
        Message:     err.Error(),
        MessageType: errorMessage,
        Progress:    100,
    }
    go response(ws, pr.json())
}()
nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
if err != nil {
    // The deferred function will automatically be called here.
    return
}
links, err := model.AllLinks()
if err != nil {
    // And in every other place where the function returns.
    return
}
```

The problem here is that there can be some pitfalls related to variable shadowing. Take this example:

```
var err error
defer func() {
    if err != nil {
        handleError(err)
    }
}()
if a, err := doSomething(); err != nil {
    return
}
```

Here's a proof of concept [on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ga8VdR9T8Ib).

The problem here is that the `err` inside of the `if` clause is not the same as the one in the upper scope; if you declare `a` in the upper scope as well, and use a single assignment `=` instead of a declaration `:=`, then it [works as expected](https://play.golang.org/p/RRU7wN4eIMc). Variable shadowing is a common pitfall, especially for beginners; [further reading](https://blog.charmes.net/post/scope-shadowing-go/).

Thus, the approach I generally use and recommend, is that of having another function. The caller generally only needs one actual return argument anyway, so it usually doesn't become very complex.

```
func a() {
    links, err := b()
    if err != nil {
        pr := progressRes{
            Type:        progressResponse,
            Message:     err.Error(),
            MessageType: errorMessage,
            Progress:    100,
        }
        go response(ws, pr.json())
        return
    }
}

func b() ([]Link, error) {
    nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    links, err := model.AllLinks()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // you probably then do something with nodes and links?
    return resolveLinks(nodes, links)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach, because it makes unit testing much easier than the other suggestions, would be:

```
func doStuff() {
    if err := doStuffWithError(); err != nil {
        pr := progressRes{
            Type:        progressResponse,
            Message:     err.Error(),
            MessageType: errorMessage,
            Progress:    100,
        }
        go response(ws, pr.json())
        return
    }
}

func doStuffWithError() error {
    nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    links, err := model.AllLinks()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Do something with nodes and links
    return nil
}
```